# admin.database.ServerValue not found in Firebase cloud functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am writing typescript for Firebase Function. I'd like to type server timestamp for firebase realtime database. However, in below code, ServerValue isn't found. I guess the library structure changed but can't find the evidence. Does anybody know something about this error?

index.ts

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
interface IStatus {
  last_changed: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
}
```

error: `....database' has no exported member 'ServerValue'.

package.json

```json
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0"
  },
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue#timestamp) you can try this method:

```
var sessionsRef = firebase.database().ref("sessions");
sessionsRef.push({
  startedAt: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
});
```